# How to Avoid casting when dealing inheritance with jackson

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, casting, jackson

**use-case** : For a config class, I need to use a translator class.

I have 3 config classes (A,B,C) and 3 translator classes (X,Y,Z).

A is parent config class and (B,C) are subclasses. Similarly X is parent translator class and (Y,Z) are subclasses.

Translator Y translates B and Translator Z translates C ie ( B -> Y, C -> Z)

NOW, I receive a string input (for config class) and I use jackson to deserialise it to a type of config class A. With Jackson, I have mentioned subTypes and Jackson is able to deserialise it to required subtypes B or C correctly.

```
A a = new ObjectMapper().readValue(inputString, A.class)
```

Now, I want to do something like :

```
if(a.type == 'B') Y.process((B)a) // Since translator Y was for B subClass
if(a.type == 'C') Z.process((C)c)//  Since translator Z was for C subClass
```

is there a way, I can avoid typecasting here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have defined `process()` like this:

```
public class Y
{
    public void process( B b ) {…}
}
```

You can add

```
…
public void process( A b ) { process( (B) b ); }
…
```

but that would only move the cast from the top further down the call path and just hides it a bit.

From your description, there is no way to avoid the cast; you need it, one or the other way.

Comment: Exactly thats my point, I tried avoiding casting, but to no success. My doubt is is it bad ? I read about casting, and I came to know in some cases casting is not avoidable everytime and not bad always. is it bad in this case ?

Comment: Usually, when casting is unavoidable, you should rethink your design. So is inheritance the right pattern in your case? (Something I cannot say anything about without knowing much more detail …). Sometimes the cast is just a dirty hack, to shortcut something. But sometimes it is really unavoidable, for various reasons. But you should be aware of these reasons …

Comment: @VinayakSangar, casting in this case is OK, and you should leave it as it is. There is no way to avoid it. You can use [Class.cast](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-cast-method-in-java-with-examples/) method but there is no point to do that.